# LINQ to Entities seemingly odd behavior

Tags: linq, group-by, linq-to-entities

I have this Linq query that translates very oddly to SQL. I get the correct results but there must be a better way. So question 1 is:

1. Why is it that in SQL I get no group by, no count and all of the
   columns are returned instead of just 2; and then the results in C# are correct? (I checked with profiler).

and question 2 is:

2. I would like to modify the query slightly so that I get also the
   results where count is 0. At the moment I only get where counts > 0
   because of the group by.

LINQ:

```
List<Tuple<string, int>> countPerType = db1.Audits
                                                .OrderBy(p => p.CreatedBy)
                                                .GroupBy(o => new { o.Type, o.CreatedBy })
                                                .ToList()
                                                .Select(g => new Tuple<string, int>(g.Select(f => f.CreatedBy + ',' + f.Type).FirstOrDefault(),
                                                                               (int?)g.Count() ?? 0))
                                                .ToList();
```

Note that if I remove the .ToList() in the middle, I get exception "only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in linq to entities".

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

You run into several problems. I think the cause of this is that you aren't aware of the difference between queries that are `AsEnumerable` and queries that are `AsQueryable`.

AsEnumerable queries contain all information to enumerate over the elements in the query. The query will be executed by your process.

An `AsQueryable` query, contains a `Expression` and a `Provider`. The Provider knows who will execute the query, and how to communicate with this executer. Quite often the executer will be a database, but it can be other things, like internet queries, jswon files etc.

In your case the executer will be a database, the language will be SQL.

When the GetEnumerator() function of your IQueryable is called, the Provider is ordered to translate the Expression into the language that the executor knows. The translated query is sent to the executor and the returned data is put into an Enumerator (not IEnumerable!)

Of course SQL does not know what a `System.Tuple` is, nor does it know functions like String.operator+

Therefore your Provider can't translate your expression into SQL. That is the reason you have to do your first ToList()

You can't make queries as IQueryable with any of your own functions, and only a limited amount of .NET functions.

[See this list of supported and unsupported Linq methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

It is not advise to use ToList() in this stadium of your query, because it enumerates all elements of your sequence, will in fact you only need an enumerator. It could be that during the rest of your query you'd only want a few elements. In that case it would be a waste to enumerate over all of them to create a list, and then to enumerate again to do the rest of your LINQ.

Instead of ToList() use [Enumerable.AsEnumerable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx). This will bring all data of the query to local memory and create an IEnumerable of it: the elements are not enumerated yet. This will allow you to call local functions with the rest of your query.

Another problem is that you transport way more data to local memory than you plan to use. One of the slower parts of database queries is the transport of data to your process. You should minimize the amount of data.

You took all Audits, and created groups of Audits that have the same values for (Type, CreatedBy). In other words: all Audits in the same group have the same values for (Type, CreatedBy). This value is also the Key of the group.

You don't want all Audits locally, you only want the Key of the group and the number of elements of this group (= the number of audits that have (Type, CreatedBy) equal to the key.

This is the only data you need to transport to local memory: Type, CreatedBy and the number of audits in the group:

```
var result = db1.Audits.GroupBy(o => new { o.Type, o.CreatedBy })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Type = group.Key.Type,
        CreatedBy = group.Key.CreatedBy,
        AuditCount = group.Count(),
    })
    .OrderBy(item => item.CreatedBy)

    // the data that is left is the data you need locally
    // bring to local memory:
    .AsEnumerable()

    // if you want you can put Type and CreatedBy into one string
    .Select(item => new
    {
        AuditType = item.Type + item.CreatedBy,
        AuditCount = item.AuditCount,
    });
```

I chose not to put the result in a Tuple, because you would lose the help from the compiler if you mix up fields. But if you really want to suit yourself.

Comment: Thanks Harald. I was aware of the two but not very used to them so it was not immediately evident to me. Makes sense and of course I did not want to load all but only those 3 results. Any ideas about my second question please?

Comment: For the second question you need the Full Outer Join your of audits with the table of all Creators, and the table of all Types. This way you include all Creators that never created an Audit, and all Types that were never audited. Linq does not know Full outer join. There are several solutions for this on stackoverlow